# Replacement of pdfs using php

Tags: php, ftp

I have the following problem:
I need to have 2 pdf files in a certain directory on my server.
These Pdf files need to be constantly( or by user interaction) synced with their originals from an external website that I don't control.
So far I have tried using the ftp_connect function in php, but godaddy seems to block that.
Is there any other way to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

Regards

wil

Comment: would you kindly submit your code?

Comment: cron job on the server to reach out and grab the latest copies, using scp/sftp?

Comment: @ J Novack, as of now there is no code. Unless you mean the ftp_connect that is definetly blocked by godaddy and confirmed by their staff.

Comment: @ Marc B Do you have an exmaple for this? I tried looking into cron jobs, but I have never really used them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
$inFile = fopen("ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf", "r");
$outFile = fopen('/tmp/short-math-guide.pdf', 'w');

if (!$inFile) {
    echo "Unable to open remote file.\n";
    exit;
}

while (!feof($inFile)) {
    fputs($outFile, fgets($inFile, 1024), 1024);
}

fclose($inFile);
fclose($outFile);
```

This also works with http:// URLs. The only requirement is that [allow_url_fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is enabled in your php.ini. It probably is.

To create a cron job, you'd have to edit your crontab with `crontab -e` and add something like this to run it every 10 minutes:

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/yourphpscript.php
```

To find out more about cron jobs, check [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) out. It was one of the first Google hits.